# Dehumidifying Basement in vacant house

Tags: basement, moisture

We are selling our house and just moved about 30 mins away.  The finished basement had a dehumidifier but no hose because we don't have a drain.  Unfortunately due to distance it is not feasible to go and empty the dehumidifier regularly and the basement is getting a musty smell. 
We do have a window in the finished area and I'm wondering if it makes sense to get a window AC?  Any other suggestions?  The only other thing I can think of is a dehumidifier with  a hose that routes to the window but I'm not sure if that is a good idea?

Comment: Is the window in a window well? Or is this an above ground window in a walk-out basement?

Answer (score 2):

If you can run a small hose out the window, get one of these [Little Giant pumps](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000CCMUCM).

I have my AC in my basement and it dumps the condensate in there and then gets pumped out via small hose.  Works great.

Comment: Good suggestion.  If the air handler is in the basement, there may even be a condensate drain next to it in the floor that the dehumidifier can use.  Also, if you use a pump like this, it may not require going through a window.  If the basement has a bathroom or utility sink, it can be discharged into the sink.

Comment: Thanks for the advise.  We do not have a  drain / sink or bathroom in the basement so unfortunately that is not an option.  So if we are running a hose out the window anyway,  is there an advantage to using the A/C with the Little Giant Pump, or is it better just to get a dehumidifier with a hose?  We don't necessarily need the AC as the basement is cool but we do need to get rid of the musty smell!

Comment: Suggestion was dehumidifier with pump; hose alone won't do it unless you have someplace downhill to send the water.  Window AC unit already dumps the condensate outside.  Presumably dehumidifier is cheaper to run so if you're really only concerned about humidity that's the route I'd go.  In order to run the AC long enough to bring down the humidity, you'd also make the basement freezing.